# Why does overflow: hidden affect width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

In the following code, in **#content** rules, `overflow:hidden` does some magic to auto adjust the `width` for the div. I tried to manually set width to a certain value such as 10000px in **#content** but the width doesn't work. The width is determined if I use `overflow:hidden|scroll|auto`.

**I'm just wondering why `overflow:hidden` does the magic?**

I've made some study on the possibility that `overflow:hidden` may start a BFC. But `display:flex` has the same effect of BFC.

To be more specific, my original attempt was to let all text in **#content** ellipsis line by line. And I found that setting the `width` in **#content** does the work correctly. But I accidentally found that I can do the same by `overflow:hidden` without setting a width. So why is that work?

```css
#container {
  padding: 12px;
  display: flex;
}

#leftblock {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#content {
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="leftblock"></div>   
  <div id="content">
    <p><b>This div will take the rest of the available width, and the <code>overflow:hidden;</code> makes sure this text doesn't fall below the <code>#floated</code> div.</b></p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce tincidunt vestibulum magna, nec rutrum lacus lobortis at. Duis convallis tincidunt neque eu viverra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam condimentum faucibus mauris, pretium varius dui tempor tempor. Aenean in elit dolor, a pellentesque urna. Vestibulum egestas metus id massa elementum quis posuere nunc tincidunt. Curabitur dapibus dictum lacus a fermentum.</p>

    <p>Quisque cursus gravida sem quis pretium. Cras cursus, neque sit amet bibendum ornare, nunc mi euismod ligula, ut cursus enim risus nec mi.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your IDs are misleading. The #floated element is not floated at all; it and #content are flex items, and flex items cannot float. This, I suspect, has nothing to do with the establishing (or not) of BFCs.

Comment: Yes, the name of ID tag is misleading and it is irrelevant to the topic. I will change it

Comment: Having said that, flex items *do* always establish formatting contexts for their contents. Still I'm not sure that's the crux of the matter, since they establish them regardless of the value of overflow, even though changing the value of overflow has adverse effects on your layout. I'll let someone more familiar with flex layout explain.

Comment: I think I agree that this is an issue about `flexbox`. It seems that when setting `overflow:hidden`, flexbox will take this flex item width as `0`. By my reckoning, `flexbox` is all about **allocating the remaining space**. Since I also set `flex:1` meaning that `flex-basis:0` and in **#leftblock** with default value `flex: 0 1 auto`, flexbox will allocate all remaining space for **#content**. It explains the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Fully Updated:

```css
#container {
        width:500px;
        padding: 12px;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    #floated {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    #content {
        margin-left: 10px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex: 1;
    }

    p {
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        margin: 8px 0;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="floated"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <p><b>This div will take the rest of the available width, and the makes sure this text doesn't fall below the <code>#floated</code> div.</b></p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce tincidunt vestibulum magna, nec rutrum lacus lobortis at. Duis convallis tincidunt neque eu viverra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam condimentum faucibus mauris, pretium varius dui tempor tempor. Aenean in elit dolor, a pellentesque urna. Vestibulum egestas metus id massa elementum quis posuere nunc tincidunt. Curabitur dapibus dictum lacus a fermentum.</p>

        <p>Quisque cursus gravida sem quis pretium. Cras cursus, neque sit amet bibendum ornare, nunc mi euismod ligula, ut cursus enim risus nec mi.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATED: You determine the width through `.container` because `flex:1;` will take up the space that is left within container. I have shrunk down the container to show you.

Comment: you can delete <code>overflow:hidden</code>in #content, and the effect is totally different. This is the jsFiddle link[link](http://jsfiddle.net/9b6bdbt9/1/)

Comment: I'm still confused. You left overflow:hidden in #content. I want to know why it resolves the width to a computed value that I cannot even change

Comment: Tweaked it once again for you. and added the explanation beneath the run code section. Also removed the overflow completely for you.

If you wish to change the width of the textarea you need to remove `flex:1;` and replace it with `flex-basis`

Comment: Maybe `flex` can introduce some distractions. You delete 'white-space:nowrap'. If you have this rule, text will be too long to stay in a line with `#floated`. And I don't want this. My first attempt was to set the width for `#content` and it worked. But I don't know why `overflow:hidden` also work.